# How to implement vuetify in laravel?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new with vuetify and i trying to implement it in laravel.

Does someone have already implement vuetify in laravel and could tell me how?

i have already install with

> npm install vuetify

and try this in App.scss

> @import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

This is my app.js file

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueRouter)


// parents componenets
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('example', require('./components/example.vue'));

import App from './views/App'
import Hello from './views/Hello'
import Home from './views/Home'

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: Home
        },
        {
            path: '/hello',
            name: 'hello',
            component: Hello,
        },
    ],
});
```

but when i try to use some  vuetify components it doesn't work.

This is my component.

```xml
<template>
  <v-app id="inspire" dark>
    <v-navigation-drawer
      clipped
      fixed
      v-model="drawer"
      app
    >
      <v-list dense>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>dashboard</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Dashboard</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
        <v-list-tile @click="">
          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title>Settings</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
    <v-toolbar app fixed clipped-left>
      <v-toolbar-side-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
      <v-toolbar-title>Application</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
        <v-layout justify-center align-center>
          <v-tooltip right>
            <v-btn icon large :href="source" target="_blank" slot="activator">
              <v-icon large>code</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <span>Source</span>
          </v-tooltip>
        </v-layout>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
    <v-footer app fixed>
      <span>&copy; 2017</span>
    </v-footer>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null
    }),
    props: {
      source: String
    }
  }
</script>
```

and try this in App.scss

> @import '~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';

but when i try to use some  vuetify components it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you wrap your app in the `v-app` component like the docs suggest?

Comment: What does your JS look like? Vuetify is a component pack, not only CSS so you'll need to add their JS as well.

Comment: Al add my app.js file. what do i need to add there?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? I don't see anything immediately wrong.

Comment: Did you mount the router to `#app`? `const app = new Vue({ router }).$mount('#app')` ??

Comment: @jostrader only the run in developer mode and this: Source map error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
Resource URL: http://localhost:8000/js/app.js
Source Map URL: vuetify.js.map
[Learn More]

Comment: And my routes are working well, see the code above the code if you have some tips jaja

Comment: It looks like your app.js isn't being compiled or is compiling wrong. It can't decipher your app.js file (unexpected character at line 1 column 1).

Comment: Here is a Laravel 5.5 starter app template: https://github.com/codeitlikemiley/vuetified

Comment: It doesn't resolve my problem but thanks @btl

Answer (score 14):

I will give you all steps to implement vuetify in laravel

1. run npm command to install vuetify in your laravel project

   ```bash
   npm install vuetify
   ```
2. go to app.js file and add this code

   ```js
   import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
      Vue.use(Vuetify); 

      const app = new Vue({
       el: '#app',
       vuetify: new Vuetify(),

   });
   ```
3. go to app.scss file and add this code

   ```js
   @import "~vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css";
   ```
4. and finally you can add this code in app.scss for vuetify fonts because if you do not add the following code you can not use  vuetify fonts and it will not be displayed

   ```js
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons');
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900');
   @import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css');
   ```

hope this can be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you for this! I've been looking for this information for longer than I'd like to admit. It works and now I can finally combine Laravel, Vue AND Vuetify!!! Why isn't this documented properly somewhere in Laravel, Vue or Vuetify documentation? Or is it and I just failed to see it?

Comment: if we directly import vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css, could we still override it with our own variables?

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same problem which solve with this

```
<body>
    <div id="admin" dark>
    <v-app id="inspire">
    ....
    </v-app>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    </body>`
```

in the javascript

```
const app = new Vue({
el: '#admin'
...
});
```